# Is question about WordPress.org site is on topic here?

Tags: support

Is question about WordPress.org site is on topic here?

This is the question, I need to ask.

> I am building WordPress plugin directory under categories. Then I want
>   allow users to sort & filter by WordPress plugins by rating, active
>   installation, last update…
>
> I have list of top WordPress plugins which are in WordPress official
>   directory. But manually updating rating, active installation, last
>   update every month will be very time consuming work. So is there any
>   API to get WordPress Plugin Active Installation, Last Update Date and
>   Rating?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you can ask how that information is getting displayed in wordpress admin, and therefor it will be ok, but generally questions about wordpress.org site itself are off-topic.